Strange coordinate transformation in this proof of Birkhoff's theorem?
In this paper a proof of Birkhoffs theorem is provided. However, there is one step that I am quite suspicious of, so I would like to know what you think about it. The relevant part of the paper for this question starts at Theorem 1 (page 3) and ends at equation (11) (page 4).

Within the paper, they consider the metric (equation (5) therein)
$$ds^2 = F(u,v) \, du^2 + 2X(u,v) \, du dv + Y^2(u,v) \, d\Omega^2 \tag{5}$$
with yet unspecified coordinates $u,v$. By Einsteins vacuum field equations they obtain the additional equation $X = \xi(u) \, \partial_v Y$ (see the two sentences starting above equation (11) therein). With this equation and the fact that $dY = (\partial_u Y \, du + \partial_v Y \, dv)$ they get the metric
$$ds^2 = \Big( F - 2 \, \partial_u Y \Big) \, du^2 + 2 \xi \, du dY + Y^2 \, d\Omega^2 \tag{$\ast$}$$
So far so good. Now within equation (11) they claim that by simple coordinate transformation, one obtains a metric of the form
$$ds^2 = F \, du^2 \pm 2 \, du dv + v^2 \, d\Omega^2 \tag{11}$$
However, this is what surprises me. Comparing equation ($\ast$) and equation (11), it seems obvious, that $Y = \pm v$ must hold, otherwise the coefficient for the round metric on the unit 2-sphere would differ. But then $dY = \pm dv$ and the metric ($\ast$) becomes
$$ds^2 = \Big( F - 2 \xi \Big) du^2 + 2\xi \, du dv + v^2 \, d\Omega^2$$
So it does not coincide with what is claimed here. Furthermore the "transformation" $Y = v$ seems a bit odd to me as $Y$ is claimed to be a function of $u$ and $v$ and this "transformation" would just neglect the dependency on the coordinate $u$.

So what is meant here and what did I misunderstand. I do not believe that there is a mistake in the paper as Birkhoff's theorem is deduced correctly, so I assume I must be mistaken somewhere.

Update 1: I corrected the mistake pointed out by "Andrew" in the comments.

The paper has $\partial_u Y$, not $\partial_v Y$, appearing in $g_{uu}$. With that change, taking $Y=v$, you get $\partial_u Y=0$ instead of $\partial_v Y = 1$, and everything works out.

Yes, I made a mistake in the coefficient of $du^2$. However, this still leaves the $\xi$ in the coefficient of $dudv$. Moreover, it still seems odd to me to just neglect the $u$-dependency of $Y$. Does that even make sense?

There is another mistake, there is no $\xi$ in the $du^2$ term.

Anyway you can have $\xi du = d\tilde{u}$ and $(F-2)\xi^{-2} = \tilde{F}$ and with abuse of notation just forget about the tilde.

ad 1.) You are correct; there is no $\xi$ in the $du^2$ term in the paper. However, I think that it still belongs there, as from
$$ds^2 = F , du^2 + 2X , dudv + ...$$
with $X = \xi , Y_v$
$$ds^2 = F , du^2 + 2 \xi , Y_v , dudv + ...$$
and with $Y_v , dv = dY - Y_u , du$
$$ds^2 = F , du^2 + 2 \xi (dY - Y_u , du) du + ...$$
which introduces $\xi$ in the $du^2$ coefficient.
ad 2.) oh ok, if one uses another symbol then this seems ok up to the point where the paper claims $Y_u = 0$. This is odd as one cannot simply neglect a coordinate dependency, right?

As already pointed out by the user @Pipe in a comment, you have a typo in your equation labelled ($\ast$). In the paper you reference it reads,
$ds^2 = \Big( F - 2 \partial_u Y \Big) \, du^2 + 2 \xi \, du dY + Y^2 d\Omega^2$,
without the $\xi$ in the $du^2$ term.
Having said that, I think the presentation in the paper could be a bit clearer. Equation ($5$) is presented in a footnote as following from a specific coordinate transformation, which includes taking $v=R$ (the radial coordinate). If you then take $Y(u, v)$ as the identity function on $v$, i.e. $Y(u, v)=v$  equation ($11$) follows immediately
If you are worried about the algebra, note that $Y=v$ implies that $\partial_u Y = 0$ and $\partial_v Y = 1$, while the total differential $dY = dv$.
edit
In response to your comment: In general you are free to choose whichever coordinates you like, although some will be more convenient. There is no reason that $Y$ has to depend on $u$ specifically. Perhaps you could explain why you think it should?

Thanks for the answer. As for the $\xi$ in the $du^2$ term: please check my comment to Pipe on the original question. I think the paper may be in error here. The algebra itself does not worry me so much as the fact that the paper takes $Y(u,v) = v$, completely neglecting the $u$ dependency of $Y$. I have a hard time understanding how this is ok. Consider e.g. Schwarzschild spacetime in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates $(v,r)$. There we have the dependencies $v(t,r)$ and so just "setting" $\partial_t v = 0$ would be quite wrong, wouldn't it?

In response to your edit: The reason why I think that neglecting the $u$ dependency is problematic is because the paper's aim (i.e. the part I am referring to) is showing that a spherically symmetric spacetime with $\Lambda < 0$ is of AdS spacetime form. Setting $Y = v = R$ only proves this theorem for a spacetime that may be written in the form
$$ds^2 = -A(T,R) , dT^2 + 2B(T,R) , dT dR + C(T,R) , dR^2 + Y^2(R) , d\Omega^2$$
(see the paper's equation (4)). But is this always possible? How does one know that a metric may always be written in such a way? (1/2)

I understand that if the coefficient of $d\Omega^2$ of some spacetime metric was for example $Y^2(T,R) = T^2\cdot R^2$, then one could always choose a new coordinate $S = T \cdot R$ such that the coefficient of $d\Omega^2$ depends only on one coordinate. But then still $\partial_T S \neq 0$ and $\partial_R S \neq 0$ in contrast to $\partial_u Y = 0$. (2/2)

I am reaching the end of my GR knowledge here, and I think the question is veering into 'review this paper' territory, which is off-topic for the site(?). I will attempt some additional comments, and hope someone more knowledgable will correct me if I say something incorrect.

Assuming eq. 4 is a valid ansatz: we would want the metric to be valid if we choose as coordinates $u=t$ and $v=R$. If we do that, and consider constant surfaces of $t$ and $R$, we would want to regain the line element of the 2-sphere (see e.g. the first answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94698/understanding-spherically-symmetric-metric/306877). This requires $Y=R$.

The most generic invariant element for a static spherically symmetric spacetime with which I am familiar is
$ds^2 = g_{00}(r, t)dt^2 + g_{rr}(r, t)dr^2 + r^2(d\Omega^2)$
with only 2 unknown scalar functions of $t$ and $\underline{x} \cdot \underline{x}$ (for a derivation see chapter 6 of Ta-Pei Cheng's 'Relativity, Gravitation, and Cosmology'). This differs from the equation 2. in the paper, which appears to be dealing with the non-static case. See the first answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453908/non-static-spherical-symmetry-spacetime for some comments on such cases.

I see. I am afraid my confusion is not fully dissolved yet -- however, this is most probably due to my lack of knowledge and comprehension of this issue. Anyhow, I very much appreciate your time and effort. It would be unfair to rob you of your well-earned bounty only because I am too dense to understand. I therefore gladly accept your answer.

If you ever gain more insight please share! I have no need of the bounty if it didn't solve your confusion - it's just 'imaginary internet points' after :)
